# Malformed date in Deserialization - Invalid format: "2017-11-19 08:03:38" is malformed at " 08:03:38"

Tags: apex, datetime

When trying to save `DateTime.now()` to the DB i'm getting the error `Invalid format: "2017-11-19 08:03:38" is malformed at " 08:03:38"`

When I use the specific format:

`String now = DateTime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm');`

Only then the date is getting saved.

Is there any solution for this without manually formatting the date? I couldn't find any method in Date\DateTime that does that for me.

**EDIT:**

After more debugging, I came up that the following row causing the error:

`return JSON.deserialize(value, DateTime.class);`

where value is `'"' + DateTime.now() + '"'`

Comment: Could you share the snippet giving the problem? And BTW manually formatting datetime means doing string manipulation which is error prone. format method is not a manual method.

Comment: @RahulSharma , I've added an edit section, thanks.

Comment: When you execute a query in anonymous mode, the datetime returned for any of the datetime fields is the same to what you are formatting your datetime. I believe may be salesforce does an internal formatting of the strings. If you are able to save the same values for the fields in DB but are not able to deserialize, I believe you should go with your workaround.

Comment: What do you mean by "trying to save DateTime.now() to the DB"?  What is the data type of the field you are trying to set, String or Date?